# New presta valve core leaks

Tags: tubeless, valves, presta

I have tubeless tires with sealant and there was sealant leaking from both presta valves after using a broken bike pump on them. After it it seems like the sealant clogged the valve a little bit and thus the air was coming out very slowly.

I changed my presta cores in a bike shop and they also pumped my wheels with their pump. Next day I check it and the valve seems to leak again. I tested it with some soapy water and it indeed was. Is it the problem with the presta valve itself, or maybe they installed a bad core? I don't have the tools to remove and replace presta cores yet and the bike shop is quite far away.

Comment: From where exactly does the leak come? Through the valve or around the nut? IMO it is not worth changing just cores in tubeless valves nor is it worth to pay for a bike shop here, unless you let all the tubeless work on them anyway. A clogged tubeless valve can be cleaned and I actually don't understand how changing the core would help. You need primarily to unclog the tube of the valve.

Comment: Tubeless valves although a pain in the rear to replace are a consumable.  Possibly the valve stem itself has been compromised so would start with that